# PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'TYPE' error (but I'm not spanning dbs)

Tags: oracle

I create a table in the FDS_APPS schema:

```
CREATE TABLE FDS_APPS.JUNK (COL1 NUMBER)
```

...and then a Hello World Package. I wanted to experiment using %TYPE to declare a local variable, Identifier2, to be the same data type as a corresponding data column, in t his case, the column COL1 in the table FDS_APPS.JUNK table but I get the error "PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'TYPE' error but same database." when I attempt to do so.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE FDS_APPS.PACKAGE1 AS
   PROCEDURE JUNKPROC(LAN_ID IN VARCHAR2, p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END PACKAGE1;
/
  
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY FDS_APPS.PACKAGE1 
AS
    PROCEDURE JUNKPROC(LAN_ID IN VARCHAR2, p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    
    COL1   NUMBER;

    --The following line of code returns this error when uncommented. Why?
    --PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'TYPE'

    --Identifier2   FDS_APPS.JUNK.COL1@TYPE; 

    BEGIN
        OPEN p_recordset FOR
        
        SELECT COL1
        --INTO COL1
        FROM FDS_APPS.JUNK  C;

    END;
END;
```

Is this a permissions issue? The table and the package are both in the same schema and I am logged on as a user that should have access to all objects in the schema, I believe.

I am an Oracle beginner. I am signed on a user MYID. I've granted this access:

```
grant execute on FDS_APPS.PACKAGE1 to FDS_APPS;
grant SELECT on FDS_APPS.JUNK to FDS_APPS ;
```

Comment: Your commented-out code has `@TYPE`, not `%TYPE`.  It is interpreting the whole thing as a reference to a remote table.

Comment: That was it. Dang  (Blush). Add your comment as an answer if you want the points. Thank you!